# fstab configuration: How to run automatic fsck scan on external harddrive at boot and automate backup to external hard drive

Tags: backup, cron, fstab, fsck

I have an external hard drive (type ext4) to which I make a daily backup of my /home folder and postgresql database via an anacron script. I have run into two problems:

1.) When the computer (Ubuntu 18.04) starts up I need to enter my login password. Then the backup commands will run as expected. What I want is that the commands get executed automatically on start-up without me having to login before anacron starts executing the script. The commands in question are:

```
rsync -acu --delete --exclude-from='/home/chh1/rsync_exclude.txt' /home/ /media/chh1/f86f92f7-bcb4-4b8e-8a64-8a210606d422/home_backup/
```

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d crewdb -w -C -F p -b -f /media/chh1/f86f92f7-bcb4-4b8e-8a64-8a210606d422/home_backup/chh1/Dropbox/postgres_backup/crewdb.backup.sql
```

Please note that the following command that is also part of the script executes without having to provide login details as it backs up to the same computer:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d crewdb -w -C -F p -b -f /home/chh1/Dropbox/postgres_backup/crewdb.backup.sql
```

2.) A backup did not work after about 50 successful backups due to disk errors. This was corrected after an fsck scan. To automate the fsck scan after every 15 boots I executed

```
sudo tune2fs -c 15 /dev/sdb1
```

I was advised by Kamil Maciorowski (Super User) that fsck would not run if fstab is not edited accordingly. That got me thinking that possibly both problems could be solved through an fstab entry. The following is an example of what I think could be a possible solution but just want to double check with someone in the know (also the syntax of the fstab entry on line 12, is that ok?). Also I am open to any other ideas that may point in the right direction:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=A3DA-B118  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sdb1       /media/chh1/f86f92f7-bcb4-4b8e-8a64-8a210606d422        ext4    rw,auto   0       2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did do which seems to have solved both problems as mentioned above is to add the following entry in /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=f86f92f7-bcb4-4b8e-8a64-8a210606d422       /media/chh1/f86f92f7-bcb4-4b8e-8a64-8a210606d422        ext4    sync,rw,suid,auto,user        0       2
```

I found 
`UUID=f86f92f7-bcb4-4b8e-8a64-8a210606d422` by running `sudo blkid /dev/sdb1`
I might mention that previous backup processes averaged about 8 minutes. The last backup with this entry in fstab took almost twice as long but returned no error message and the backups were made and seem alright. So I will be trying to find out why it takes that long.